# Bitmap cannot be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

I'm looking at creating a small program in C# that takes in an image, crops it and spits out the cropped image as a new image.

I'm just getting started with the program and I'm having some errors regarding `System.Drawing` and the `Bitmap` data type.

I've declared a Bitmap object in `main()` and receive this error:
[image: Bitmap error]

So next thing I try is declaring `using System.Drawing.Common;`. Doing so gives me this error:
[image: System Drawing Common error]

I am serious stumped with what to do as I can't seem to find anything online. Any help would be amazing!

If it helps, I'm using **Visual Studio Code** to write my code and my OS is **MacOS Catalina**. I've also attached the full code file. Its not much but that's all I've got.

Thanks in advance!

```cs
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Common;

namespace consoleproject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will likely need to add a reference to `System.Drawing`, or if this is .Net core, add the nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the System.Drawing.Common package. It is not added by default in .Net core projects. To add it:

```
dotnet add package System.Drawing.Common
```